# Multiple python version in one project

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyenv

I have a project which is running by Python 3.10
I want to add new_script.py to my project (by import), but Problem is this new_script.py only works with Python 3.7

How can I handle this new_script.py to run by python 3.7 while Main.py is running by Python 3.10?

```
Main.py (running with 3.10)
--- import new_script (should run with 3.7)
```

I searched a lot, but I didn't find any solution for running two version of python at same time in one project.

Comment: Not possible. One process, one Python version.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run one file with two different versions of Python

**Solution:**

> You have to match the main file Python version with your script Python
> version or your script Python version with the Python version of your
> main file.